# Swift HealthKit Trigger Heart Rate Sample

Tags: swift, apple-watch, healthkit

I'm able to read average heart rate data from HealthKit for a period of time (duration of workout) with the below code.

However, when I look in the Apple Health app, it shows that the heart rate samples from the Apple Watch are taken very infrequently (every 15-30 min). This makes my average HR read for the period quite inaccurate.

How can I trigger HealthKit to sample (gather) Heart Rate data from the watch and write it to HealthKit?

```
    let endDate = (calendar as NSCalendar).date(byAdding: NSCalendar.Unit.minute, value: duration, to: startDate, options: NSCalendar.Options())
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, options: HKQueryOptions())

    let squery = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: heartRateType, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: HKStatisticsOptions.discreteAverage, completionHandler: { (qurt, result, errval) -> Void in

        guard errval == nil else { print("error"); completion(0.0, errval); return }

        var averageHeartRate : Double = 0.0
        if (result != nil && result!.averageQuantity() != nil) {
            let quantity : HKQuantity = result!.averageQuantity()!
            averageHeartRate = quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count().unitDivided(by: HKUnit.minute()))
        }
    })
```

Comment: Have you started a `HKWorkoutSession` before taking the measurements?

Comment: @DávidPásztor I did not, once I started it was good, thanks!

Comment: @DávidPásztor I started the workout but it doesn't seem to stop when I call end session. The hr monitor continues to stay on and the watch app remains in foreground. Any ideas how I can stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get more frequent heart rate data from Apple Watch, the user must be running an app on their watch that is tracking an `HKWorkoutSession`. If your app has a paired watchOS app that tracks workouts, you can start a workout from the iPhone by using [startWatchApp(with workoutConfiguration:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/1648358-startwatchapp).

Comment: Thanks, I added and this fixed my issue!
Note I also needed to add WKBackgroundModes and UIBackgroundModes

Comment: I started the workout but it doesn't seem to stop when I call end session. The hr monitor continues to stay on and the watch app remains in foreground. Any ideas how I can stop this?

Comment: @achen1217 Can you please help me with the sample on how you did HKWorkoutSession and how you used UIBackgroundModes and WKBackgroundModes for this?

Comment: It's works, but Apple doesn't let us to Appstore. The main reason is: the app doesn't have fitness core functionality!